# What is the best way to selectively delete messages from a Qmail queue?

Tags: email

We're trying to delete 80% or 90% of the emails from a ~200k message queue.  Ideally, we would be able to select the messages using regex.

I can see the messages in the queue folder, but just deleting the files seems dangerous.

Are there any utilities or established patterns for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way. You can google for **qmail-delete** or a tool like

http://improvise.wordpress.com/2008/03/08/how-to-delete-a-message-from-qmail-queue/

Answer (score 3):

I usually use qmHandle. http://sourceforge.net/projects/qmhandle/